# Count rows in C# list with same Group and set as int value on other property

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, lambda, properties

I need help to solve this. 
I have used Console Application to solve this and I am stuck.

Every row in ORDER needs to have an unique value inside a group med same GROUP-value. The Max-value on ORDER inside the group need to be Count of Rows -1 and Min value has to be 0. The sorting doesnt matter.

It only needs to be an UNIQUE value between min and max.

Example: 012345 or 041532

```
ID  GROUP  VALUE  ORDER
1   1      10     0
2   1      2      0
3   2      1      0
4   3      2      0
5   3      6      0
6   3      1      0
7   3      9      0
```

GROUP 1 have 2(-1) Rows, ORDER value has to be 0-1.
GROUP 2 have 1(-1) Rows, ORDER value has to be 0.
GROUP 3 have 4(-1) Rows, ORDER value has to be 0-3.

End Result:

```
ID  GROUP  VALUE  ORDER
1   1      10     0
2   1      2      1
3   2      1      0
4   3      2      0
5   3      6      1
6   3      1      3
7   3      9      2
```

Here is the properties i have used.

```
public class OrderRow
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int GROUP { get; set; }
    public int VALUE { get; set; }
    public int ORDER { get; set; }
}

            new OrderRow {ID = 1,  GROUP = 1, VALUE = 10, ORDER = 0},
            new OrderRow {ID = 2,  GROUP = 1, VALUE = 2, ORDER = 0},
            new OrderRow {ID = 3,  GROUP = 2, VALUE = 1, ORDER = 0},
            new OrderRow {ID = 4,  GROUP = 3, VALUE = 2, ORDER = 0},
            new OrderRow {ID = 5,  GROUP = 3, VALUE = 6, ORDER = 0},
            new OrderRow {ID = 6,  GROUP = 3, VALUE = 1, ORDER = 0},
            new OrderRow {ID = 7,  GROUP = 3, VALUE = 9, ORDER = 0},
```

THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go like follows:

```
       List<OrderRow> orders = new List<OrderRow>() {
            new OrderRow { ID = 1, GROUP = 1, VALUE = 10, ORDER = 0 },
            new OrderRow { ID = 2, GROUP = 1, VALUE = 2, ORDER = 0 },
            new OrderRow { ID = 3, GROUP = 2, VALUE = 1, ORDER = 0 },
            new OrderRow { ID = 4, GROUP = 3, VALUE = 2, ORDER = 0 },
            new OrderRow { ID = 5, GROUP = 3, VALUE = 6, ORDER = 0 },
            new OrderRow { ID = 6, GROUP = 3, VALUE = 1, ORDER = 0 },
            new OrderRow { ID = 7, GROUP = 3, VALUE = 9, ORDER = 0 },
        };

        foreach (var item in orders.GroupBy(order => order.GROUP))
        {
            int order = 0;
            foreach (var item2 in item)
            {
                item2.ORDER = order++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you!! :) @user3598756

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer solved your question you may want to accept it! Thank you